# socket.io, nginx, Error serving static, increased trafiic

Tags: performance, nginx, socket.io, gateway

I have some issue with socket.io and nginx configuration.

After ouer website had increased traffic we saw that sometimes sockets get that kind of error: Error serving static /socket.io.js and we lose a socket connection.

After clicks couple times F5 socket.io is connected.
We have 100-150 users per/pick it's not that much, but we still have a perfomance issue in socket.io.

We read many articles about nginx, fpm perfomance, but nothing helps.

And it's tricky becouse any other file (js,css, etc.) never get 500 Bad gateway, only socket/socket.io.js get it.

If someone had similar issue?

My nginx config for socket.io looks like this:

```
server {

           listen 443 ssl;
           ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ao-certs/socket/bundle.pem;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ao-certs/socket/private.key;
           ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!kEDH;
           ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
           server_name socket.customericare.com;
           location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081; #this is the ip:port where your node app runs root /var/www/yoursitename; expires 30d; #uncomment this is you want to name an index file: #index index.php index.html;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    access_log off;
            }
    }
```

nginx app config:

```
server {
       listen  443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ao-certs/app/bundle.pem;
       sssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ao-certs/app/private.key;
       server_name app.customericare.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log off;

  location / {
        root /var/www/vhosts/app.customericare.com/;
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }

  # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    root /var/www/vhosts/app.customericare.com/;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }
   location ~ \.php$ {
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/app.customericare.com/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     app.customericare.com;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  }
```

error.log from nginx:

```
2014/08/18 15:15:03 [error] 30627#0: *84775 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
2014/08/18 15:15:36 [error] 30624#0: *86344 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.219.114.213, server: _, request: "GET /api/history?key=d67d8ab4f4c10bf22aa353e27879133c&callback=jQuery1910025671478084960175_1408367787961&url=%2F128202%2CPlytka-scienna-Ashen-1-dekor-298x598-Tubadzin.html&referer=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.pl%252Faclk%253Fsa%253Dl%2526ai%253DCxtBPmPzxU761JoHs7QbC2oKoCdG4s9wG0f_o2oIBuYyOqvABCAYQBCC2VCgIUJLyycf4_____wFg6fS7hcAaoAGn9ZHdA8gBB6kCViPo5gVvlT6qBCZP0CEZtRELzRwscpJrLVykYG116t-ZOVLU2JZhK303WoihaBRHCoAFkE7ABQWgBiaAB8GK7iKQBwOoB6a-G-ASs-i62Ye6x6L-AQ%2526sig%253DAOD64_247fMXEARqfH0TFZPOKDesc7km8w%2526ctype%253D5%2526rct%253Dj%2526q%253D%2526ved%253D0CKUBELsX%2526adurl%253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fclickserve.dartsearch.net%252Flink%252Fclick%25253Flid%25253D93700004546857158%252526ds_s_kwgid%25253D58700000218636004%252526ds_e_adid%25253D34995694433%252526ds_e_source%25253Dpla%252526ds_e_product_target_id%25253D64512820793%252526ds_e_product_id%25253D128202%252526ds_url_v%25253D2%252526ds_dest_url%25253Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fnexterio.pl%252F128202%252CPlytka-scienna-Ashen-1-dekor-298x598-Tubadzin.html&res=1366x768&domain=nexterio.pl&_=1408367787963 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "app.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/128202,Plytka-scienna-Ashen-1-dekor-298x598-Tubadzin.html?gclid=CP-0j-zynMACFabLtAod5VsAMQ"
2014/08/18 15:15:36 [error] 30624#0: *86486 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.219.114.213, server: _, request: "GET /ajax/initplugin/?callback=jQuery1910025671478084960175_1408367787964&apiKey=d67d8ab4f4c10bf22aa353e27879133c&sectionId=&userId=843579&companyIds=040206775abd329f334c1b67a0471423&_=1408367787965 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "app.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/128202,Plytka-scienna-Ashen-1-dekor-298x598-Tubadzin.html?gclid=CP-0j-zynMACFabLtAod5VsAMQ"
2014/08/18 15:15:36 [error] 30624#0: *84325 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.8.230.170, server: _, request: "GET /api/check-cookie?key=d67d8ab4f4c10bf22aa353e27879133c&callback=jQuery19103423224048516038_1408367780109&_=1408367780110 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "app.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/16603,16599,16590,Utrzymanie-czystosci-i-przechowywanie_Kosze-na-smieci.html"
2014/08/18 15:15:36 [error] 30623#0: *86466 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.252.56.2, server: _, request: "GET /api?key=d67d8ab4f4c10bf22aa353e27879133c HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "app.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/15354,15337,15337,Elektronarzedzia_Wiertarko-wkretarki.html?utm_source=wp&utm_medium=baner_branding&utm_campaign=Portale&utm_term=gif&utm_content=wiertarko-wkretarki"
2014/08/18 15:15:36 [error] 30624#0: *85652 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.8.39.41, server: _, request: "GET /api/check-cookie?key=d67d8ab4f4c10bf22aa353e27879133c&callback=jQuery19108185782760291924_1408367791167&_=1408367791168 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "app.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/16392,16355,16355,Oswietlenie-wewnetrzne_Lampy-wiszace.html?filtry=&utm_source=interia&utm_medium=baner_branding&utm_campaign=Portale&utm_term=130x95&utm_content=lampy_wew&s=2"
2014/08/18 15:19:02 [error] 30624#0: *96228 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.6.7.75, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/oYFh4Kf9B4wRgNwUBZ25 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1/websocket/oYFh4Kf9B4wRgNwUBZ25", host: "socket.customericare.com"
2014/08/18 15:19:02 [error] 30624#0: *96232 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.160.172.85, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/ABhF76o3llLT7bZ7BZ27 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1/websocket/ABhF76o3llLT7bZ7BZ27", host: "socket.customericare.com"
2014/08/18 15:19:02 [error] 30626#0: *93339 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.156.124.172, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://www.expander.pl/serwis-ekonomiczny/produkty/KwartetGwiazd2II.html"
2014/08/18 15:19:02 [error] 30627#0: *96237 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.10.9.214, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1//hIWIh5ovD9hdQtT2BZ1e/?disconnect=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1//hIWIh5ovD9hdQtT2BZ1e/?disconnect=1", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/16392,16355,16355,Oswietlenie-wewnetrzne_Lampy-wiszace.html?utm_source=interia&utm_medium=baner_branding&utm_campaign=Portale&utm_term=130x95&utm_content=lampy_wew"
2014/08/18 15:20:02 [error] 30624#0: *99046 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
2014/08/18 15:25:03 [error] 30626#0: *111928 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
2014/08/18 15:30:02 [error] 30623#0: *124459 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
2014/08/18 15:32:28 [error] 30627#0: *125573 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.8.2.57, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/16392,16355,16355,Oswietlenie-wewnetrzne_Lampy-wiszace.html?filtry=&utm_source=interia&utm_medium=baner_branding&utm_campaign=Portale&utm_term=130x95&utm_content=lampy_wew&s=7"
2014/08/18 15:33:11 [error] 30626#0: *132144 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.16.160.242, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/133737,Lampa-wiszaca-wielopunktowa-Bazylea-6xG9-40W-Light-Prestige.html"
2014/08/18 15:34:05 [error] 30627#0: *134505 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.36.180.126, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/133763,Firana-Benita-W07900-200x180-Wisan.html?utm_source=domodi&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=link&utm_campaign=homebook&utm_term=Firany"
2014/08/18 15:34:05 [error] 30627#0: *125730 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.88.56.33, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1//3gIJTOfkZO32R41ZBa4i/?disconnect=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1//3gIJTOfkZO32R41ZBa4i/?disconnect=1", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/16388,16386,16355,Oswietlenie-wewnetrzne_Oprawy-punktowe-schodowe.html?params=f4:14374106&cid=16388"
2014/08/18 15:34:05 [error] 30624#0: *134526 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 83.21.82.46, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/I-xxmL26tJWjxv9bBa4w HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/1/websocket/I-xxmL26tJWjxv9bBa4w", host: "socket.customericare.com"
2014/08/18 15:35:03 [error] 30623#0: *137234 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
2014/08/18 15:36:35 [error] 30623#0: *140441 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 80.94.30.44, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/?"
2014/08/18 15:36:35 [error] 30627#0: *140440 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.10.14.42, server: socket.customericare.com, request: "GET /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js", host: "socket.customericare.com", referrer: "http://nexterio.pl/szukaj.php?fraza=przej%C5%9Bci%C3%B3ka+e27+e14&bnh=&search=&clear=1"
```

Server Load:

```
CPU:  ~15-40%
Mem: ~2000/8000 MB
Swap: ~5/3904 MB
```

PM2 monit:

```
CPU process: ~7-20%
Mem: ~136 MB
```

In node.js (pm2) when I restart proces I have about 20-30MB memory usage. 
After couple second it's increase to ~130MB.

Comment: is this error associated with some kind of slowdown from your websocket server? I see you haven't set an explicit ```proxy_send_timeout``` or 
   ```proxy_read_timeout``` on the location block for your websocket subdomain. I have mine set to 300s.

Comment: hi, how did you solve this, thanks!